# Fusion Table layers not showing up in my google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

this is my first time make a map using Fusion Tables, I want two layers to display in this map, one with markers, and another with polygons,

I was using the styling shown in the tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables to try out, but

I don't know what I've done wrong that neither is showing up?

http://www.missromi.com/maps/miami-test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A layer will be shown on the map, when you set his map-property.

You set the map-property of `layer` in line 55:

```
layer.setMap(map);
```

...but there is no object `layer`, the objects are `layer1` and `layer2`.

you  must call:

```
layer1.setMap(map);
layer2.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Fusion Tables Layer wizard to generate the code that layers your two maps together, and then modify from there:

http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html

-Rebecca